# How to change background music for different scenes in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to get the menu and other scenes to play different music, but I can't get anything to work. Here's the code:

Setting up pygame:

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900,600),0,32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
```

Setting up the music:

```
pygame.mixer.init() 
menuMusic = pygame.mixer.Sound("cs.mp3") 
scene1Music = pygame.mixer.Sound("ut.mp3")
                    
menu_channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(0)
scene1_channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
```

The class to switch scenes:

```
class GameState():
    def __init__(self):
        self.scene = self.menu
        
    def menu(self, event_list): 
        menu_channel.play(menuMusic, loops=-1, fade_ms=5000)    
        screen.blit(font.render("Menu", True, 'white'), (60, 150))   
   
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_presses = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()            
                if mouse_presses[0]:
                    self.state = self.scene1
                
    def scene1(self, event_list):
        scene1_channel.play(scene1Music, loops=-1, fade_ms=5000)
        screen.blit(font.render("This is Scene1", True, 'white'), (WIDTH/15, 150))
```

Main game loop:

```
game = GameState()
while True:
    event_list = pygame.event.get()  
  
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()
    
    game.scene(event_list)
    
    clock.tick(24)
```

For now it only works when I move them both to the begining, although that's not what I want because they'll be playing together at the same time. But if I move `menu_channel.play(menuMusic, loops=-1, fade_ms=5000)` into the menu method, nothing will play. Same goes for `scene1_channel.play(scene1Music, loops=-1, fade_ms=5000)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're restarting the sound every frame, when you should do it just once. Quick and dirty solution is to have a boolean `music_started` that you switch, but a better solution is to rethink your game state class.

A class is meant to encapsulate one thing, but you're putting all scenes into one object. Instead, it's common to define a `Scene` class and create sub-classes for each scene. This class should usually have methods like `on_start`, `on_update`, and `on_exit` (and probably more). Then you can make sure your scene does the right thing.

```
import pygame

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480


class Scene:
    def on_start(self):
        pass

    def update(self, events, dt):
        pass

    def on_exit(self):
        pass


class Menu(Scene):
    def __init__(self, screen, scenes):
        self.scenes  = scenes
        self.screen  = screen
        self.font    = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
        self.music   = pygame.mixer.Sound("cs.mp3")
        self.channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(0)

    def on_start(self):
        self.channel.play(self.music, loops=-1, fade_ms=5000)

    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                left_click, *_ = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
                if left_click:
                    return self.scenes['game']

        self.screen.blit(self.font.render("Menu", True, 'white'), (60, 150))
        return self

    def on_exit(self):
        self.channel.stop()


class Game(Scene):
    def __init__(self, screen, scenes):
        self.scenes = scenes
        self.screen = screen
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
        self.music = pygame.mixer.Sound("cs.mp3")
        self.channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(0)
        self.timer = 0

    def on_start(self):
        self.channel.play(self.music, loops=-1, fade_ms=5000)

    def update(self, events, dt):
        # Go back to menu if there hasn't been any events for 5 seconds.
        if not events:
            self.timer += dt
            if self.timer >= 5:
                return self.scenes['menu']
        else:
            self.timer = 0

        self.screen.blit(self.font.render("This is Scene1", True, 'white'), (WIDTH / 15, 150))
        return self

    def on_exit(self):
        self.channel.stop()


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 600), 0, 32)
    clock  = pygame.time.Clock()

    # All the scenes.
    scenes = {}
    scenes['menu'] = Menu(screen, scenes)
    scenes['game'] = Game(screen, scenes)

    # Start with the menu.
    scene = scenes['menu']
    scene.on_start()
    while True:
        dt = clock.tick(30) / 1000.0

        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        # Switch scenes if there is a new scene.
        new_scene = scene.update(events, dt)
        if new_scene is not scene:
            # If there is a new scene, make sure to allow the old
            # scene to exit and the new scene to start.
            scene.on_exit()
            scene = new_scene
            scene.on_start()

        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried both solutions and wanted to try putting the scenes in different classes like you suggested, but I've encountered 1 tiny problem with the code you provided. When I run the code, the window will pop up with a black screen without any sounds for about a second at first,  before the actual visuals/sounds show up. This doesn't happen when I use my initial structure and everything will just show up immediatey when I run it. I'm wondering if there's a way to fix this so I can just go ahead and abandon my initial code structure and transfer the contents to the new one.

Comment: @hmm The problem you're describing is because it takes some time to load the music in, so your window is created all black, it's waiting for the sound to be loaded, and then continue. This should be the case in your initial code also, and I tried out the code you provided and got the same result. It is the expected result. **However**, if you run the code again it's highly likely (but not guaranteed) that the data is in the [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) and therefore loads almost immediately.

Comment: @hmm The solution to the problem is a hard one, and depends on what you want to happen. If you want the display to open up after your sound has been loaded, then you need to load everything before you create the display. Switching between scenes might still cause an delay which is unavoidable, but there are different ways to make it less noticeable, again depending on how your game works and what would make most sense.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway! I'll just move on to the new class structure. The code I gave here was a very stripped down version of what I actually had and now it just gives me a black window without sounds when I run this, so I can't even test and compare it with yours now. But when I run my actual initial code VS the revised version based on yours, the former always loads immediately while the latter takes about a second. I don't think it's due to cache because I constantly test one right after the other.  I'll just assume it's something weird on my end and leave it as another unexplained mystery